# unable to send data using udp in c#

Tags: c#, udp

Hello I am developing sample application for demonstration of udp client to send data from client to server. I have created console application and below is my code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            senddata();
            while (true)
            {
                try { 
                UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(9999);
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                string result;
                result = returnData.ToString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            void senddata()
            {
                UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(9999);

                udpClient.Connect("10.170.84.163", 9999);
                Byte[] senddata1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");
                udpClient.Send(senddata1, senddata1.Length);

            }
        }
    }
```

whenever  Byte[] receiveBytes is executed i get my empty black screen and nothing is going to happen. Can someone tell me how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: maybe udp is blocked on the router or similar?

Comment: Thanks. How can i check this?

Comment: "i get my empty black screen and nothing is going to happen" what does that mean? It hangs? Because I don't see you write `result` variable to console or something, so black screen is kind of expected.

Comment: i wrote Console.WriteLine(result); and it doesnt hang neither display anything.

Comment: an empty `catch` block is never a good idea. At lease print the `e.Message` to console. This way you will at least know wether your code breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You send data to udp port (via `senddata()`) *before* starting a listener on that port, and you do this only once, so there is no chance listener might receive it.
2. There is no need to bind `UdpClient` to specific port when sending data, especially to the same port on which you are listening with another `UdpClient`. Just use `UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();` to let it use any available port for sending.
3. Since you are testing - there is no need to send data to your external ip, send to loopback interface instead: `udpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 9999);`.
4. `UdpClient` implements `IDisposable`, so dispose it when you are done.
5. Your `while (true)` loop will not work, because you don't dispose `UdpClient`, so on second iteration of the loop, second `UdpClient` will try to bind to the same 9999 port and fail, because there is already listener (which you didn't dispose) on that same port.

Your code with fixes above (obviously that is not "production" code so I won't add things like cancellation and so on, only fixes to be able to see message is coming):

```
static void senddata() {
    // send message every 100 ms
    while (true) {
        // wrap in using
        using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient()) {
            // loopback
            udpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 9999);
            Byte[] senddata1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");
            udpClient.Send(senddata1, senddata1.Length);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    // run sending in background
    Task.Run(() => senddata());

    try {
        // wrap in using
        using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(9999)) {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            // move while loop here
            while (true) {
                // this blocks until message is received
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                Console.WriteLine(returnData);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // do something meaningful
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're outputting the received string.

Something like this....

```
string result;
result = returnData.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following:

```
IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

To use the port 9999 rather than a random port. I'm honestly somewhat surprised that doesn't throw an exception.

Note that binding to a random port as a server is not atypical but the remote end will need some way to discover that random port I..E. the way ftp uses a second port for actual file data transfer, that port number is sent as part of the message starting the transfer.

Comment: Thanks it does not work for me. Same error i am getting.